# How to make a nested select pull from only data available in the main select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Im creating a report in SSRS Report Builder 2016.

I have a set of data that contains a set of agencies and the amount of money that billed to each agency for each month (TotalBilled). Every agency can have multiple values for TotalBilled. I want to find the median TotalBilled value for each agency.

I calculate the median value inside my query, but it pulls from all TotalBilled in all agencies, and not just the TotalBilled related to the agency I have set in my parameter.

Here is my Dataset query:

```
DECLARE @Cnt int = (SELECT COUNT(TotalBilled) FROM InvoiceLine)

select 
     a.AgencyID
     a.startdate,
     a.enddate,
     [TotalBilled],

     ((SELECT TOP 1 TotalBilled
     FROM   (
         SELECT  TOP (@Cnt/2) TotalBilled
         FROM    InvoiceLine I
         WHERE   TotalBilled is NOT NULL
         ORDER BY TotalBilled ASC
         ) AS I
     ORDER BY TotalBilled DESC) +
     (
     SELECT TOP 1 TotalBilled
     FROM   (
         SELECT  TOP (@Cnt/2) TotalBilled
         FROM    InvoiceLine I
         WHERE   TotalBilled is NOT NULL
         ORDER BY TotalBilled DESC
         ) AS I
     ORDER BY TotalBilled ASC)) / 2 AS MedianTotalBilled

from Agency a
left join invoiceLine invl
    on a.InvoiceID = invl.InvoiceID
where (a.agencyid in (@agency))
and (a.startdate >= @startdate and a.enddate <= @enddate)
```

What is the right way to change my meidan value calculation so that it is affected by my parameter and not just pulling from the whole database?

EDIT:

Also adding the joins into the median calc did not bring about the expected Value of the median. Here is what im currently trying:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 TotalBilled
     FROM   (
         SELECT  TOP (@Cnt/2) TotalBilled
         left join invoiceLine invl
              on a.InvoiceID = invl.InvoiceID
         where (a.agencyid in (@agency))
         and (a.startdate >= @startdate and a.enddate <= @enddate)
         and  TotalBilled is NOT NULL
         ORDER BY TotalBilled ASC
     ) AS I
 ORDER BY TotalBilled DESC)
```

Comment: would adding a  and a.InvoiceID = l.InvoiceID in both sub selects not be what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thanks, im unsure how to properly add that join into the select. but it does seem like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to add the row limit into the sub select as follows

```
DECLARE @Cnt int = (SELECT COUNT(TotalBilled) FROM InvoiceLine)
    select 
         a.AgencyID
         a.startdate,
         a.enddate,
         [TotalBilled],

         ((SELECT TOP 1 TotalBilled
         FROM   (
             SELECT  TOP (@Cnt/2) TotalBilled
             FROM    InvoiceLine I
             WHERE   TotalBilled is NOT NULL
             and  a.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID --new
             ORDER BY TotalBilled
             ) AS I
         ORDER BY TotalBilled DESC) +
         (
         SELECT TOP 1 TotalBilled
         FROM   (
             SELECT  TOP (@Cnt/2) TotalBilled
             FROM    InvoiceLine I
             WHERE   TotalBilled is NOT NULL
             and  a.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID --new
             ORDER BY TotalBilled DESC
             ) AS I
         ORDER BY TotalBilled ASC)) / 2 AS MedianTotalBilled

    from Agency a
    left join invoiceLine invl
        on a.InvoiceID = invl.InvoiceID
    where (a.agencyid in (@agency))
    and (a.startdate >= @startdate and a.enddate <= @enddate)
```

Edit: 
the selector for row count needs to be limited as well

```
select 
     a.AgencyID
     a.startdate,
     a.enddate,
     [TotalBilled],



    ((SELECT TOP 1 TotalBilled
     FROM   (
         SELECT  TOP (
             (
                SELECT  count(*)
                FROM    InvoiceLine I
                WHERE   TotalBilled is NOT NULL
                and  a.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID 
             )


             /2) TotalBilled
         FROM    InvoiceLine I
         WHERE   TotalBilled is NOT NULL
         and  a.InvoiceID = I.InvoiceID --new
         ORDER BY TotalBilled
         ) AS I
     ORDER BY TotalBilled DESC)

from Agency a
left join invoiceLine invl
    on a.InvoiceID = invl.InvoiceID
where (a.agencyid in (@agency))
and (a.startdate >= @startdate and a.enddate <= @enddate)
```

Comment: Ok, this looks good. Will the count of TotalBilled be correct, or will I need to change how to count the total for this?

Comment: DECLARE @Cnt int = (SELECT COUNT(TotalBilled) FROM InvoiceLine) will need to change as a sub select per line

Comment: Thanks you for your help! it has been invaluable to me!